# Validate Drop down asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, validation

I have following drop down

```
        <li><span>State: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAppState" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList></span></li>
```

It gets populated on page load () using below function

```
          private void ddlAppState_DataBind()
{
    string myXMLfile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ActiveStates.xml");
    System.Data.DataSet dsStudent = new System.Data.DataSet();

    dsStudent.ReadXml(myXMLfile);
    ddlAppState.DataSource = dsStudent;
    ddlAppState.DataValueField = "StateID";
    ddlAppState.DataTextField = "StateName";
    ddlAppState.DataBind();
}
```

Inititally the value in drop down is "--------" but on backend it maps to "FD" i want to validate if the "-----" is selected whose value if i get by doing ddlAppState.SelectedValue.ToString() is a string "FD" then i do not want to call the onlick function of button .

Button OnClick

```
 <asp:Button Style="left: 0px; position: relative" ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                CssClass="lbSearch closeform" Text="Search" Width="80px" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"  >
            </asp:Button></div>

 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
            if (ddlAppState.SelectedValue.ToString() == "FD" && ddlAppMode.SelectedValue.ToString() == "S")
      {
          SelectState.Text = " Please Select State ";
          return;
            }

            SelectState.Text = "";
        BindGridViewZipConfirmation1();
```

//          clearFields();
        }

Any idea of how it can be done . Thank You

Comment: States are presenst in an xml file here

Comment: Where is this onclick function? Please include the code. Have you tried using a `TextChanged` event? It won't fire the onclick unless the `SelectedValue` has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether the `SelectedIndex` is greater than zero (the default value), then use `SelectedValue` if it is. Otherwise just `return` from the click handler.

Comment: Damn i should have checked it in onclick function . I was checking it in databind function and returning error from there which was causing issue .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate in client side. Please try this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlName" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select" value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"    ErrorMessage="Please select"  ControlToValidate="ddlName" ValidationGroup="btnSave" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="-1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```